# THREE.js Texture to Sphere with React

Tags: reactjs, three.js, texture-mapping

I am trying to load a flag (gif) texture to a sphere geometry in THREE.js, but the caveat is I am using React to do this.

```
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const flag = getFlagForCountry(flags, x.id),
      texture = textureLoader.load(require(`../assets/images/flags/${flag.name}.gif`));

const mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        transparent: true,
        opacity: .5,
        map: texture
    });

const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 10), mat);
    sphere.overdraw = true;
```

When I remove the `map: texture` property I am able to see the sphere in the scene, but then when I add back in the texture it is simply a black screen. I know the docs for `TextureLoader` say `url` is a string, but I am not getting any errors and in fact I am getting warnings that make it appear like something is working. Has anyone had success loading a texture onto a sphere using `require()` in React.

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (1181x788). Resized to 1024x512 
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="/static/media/Argentina.4c3ff3da.gif">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend passing the image path directly to the `.load()` method rather than passing it via `require()`. Also, I suggest using the `TextureLoader` callback, to ensure that your texture object is valid and fully loaded, before trying to make use of it.

You can make use of the callback in this way:

```
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const flag = getFlagForCountry(flags, x.id)'

// Use the loaders callback
textureLoader.load(`../assets/images/flags/${flag.name}.gif`, function(texture) {

  // The texture object has loaded and is now avalible to be used
  const mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          transparent: true,
          opacity: .5,
          map: texture
      });

  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 10), mat);
  sphere.overdraw = true;

  // Add sphere to your scene ... scene.add(sphere); 
});
```

As a final note, consider adjusting your image filepath to an absolute path (by removing the `..`) if your `assets` directory is located in the same directory that your webserver is running from.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";

var earthMesh;

class ThreeScene extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight;
    //ADD SCENE
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //ADD CAMERA
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.z = 8;
    //ADD RENDERER
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setClearColor("#263238");
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    //ADD CUBE
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "#0F0",
      wireframe: true
    });
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.cube);

    //Add SPHERE
    //LOAD TEXTURE and on completion apply it on box
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load(
      "data:image/png;base64,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",
      this.onLoad,
      this.onProgress,
      this.onError
    );

    //LIGHTS
    var lights = [];
    lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0x304ffe, 1, 0);
    lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
    lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
    lights[0].position.set(0, 200, 0);
    lights[1].position.set(100, 200, 100);
    lights[2].position.set(-100, -200, -100);
    this.scene.add(lights[0]);
    this.scene.add(lights[1]);
    this.scene.add(lights[2]);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stop();
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  }
  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  };
  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  };
  animate = () => {
    this.earthMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    this.renderScene();
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  };
  renderScene = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  };

  onLoad = texture => {
    var objGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 35, 35);
    var objMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      shading: THREE.FlatShading
    });

    this.earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(objGeometry, objMaterial);
    this.scene.add(this.earthMesh);
    this.renderScene();
    //start animation
    this.start();
  };

  onProgress = xhr => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
  };

  // Function called when download errors
  onError = error => {
    console.log("An error happened" + error);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px" }}
        ref={mount => {
          this.mount = mount;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default ThreeScene;
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/kw7l49nw1r